# Python exits CSV File before the end of File

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

I have a function that takes a csv or txt file uploaded in my django app, reads all the file and processes it into a python list. I noticed that if for some reason the file contains blank lines, it does not read to the end of the file and it returns an empty list. Do you think I am missing something  ? Here is my code.

Yeah I could just tell the user to make sure the  file does not contain any blank line, but I am thinking I could just make the script smart enough to not break until end of file whilst reading.

## django #form #class #view

def read_the_file_content(self,file,filetype,message,sender):
        print "inside readfile"

```
    data = []


    for row in csv.reader(file):

        print row
        num = str(re.sub("[^0-9]","",row[0]))
        #print num
        if num.startswith('0'):
           phone_num =  '234' + num[1:]

        else:
            phone_num =  num



        data.append(phone_num)     


    if data == []:

        return []
    else:
        return set(data)
```

## csvFIleData

07037062611
07063724920

08065537377
08168571687

Comment: `row` is an empty list for blank lines so `num = str(re.sub("[^0-9]","",row[0]))` should raise an index error. Are you sure the function is just returning an empty list?

Comment: It was not raising no error. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is not with the csv-reading portion of your code. Here is a simplified version of the csv-reading portion:

```
import csv

def read_csv(file):
    data = []
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        data.append(row)
    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':

    path = "test.csv"
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        print(read_csv(f))
```

Output is:

```
[['07037062611 07063724920'], [], ['08065537377 08168571687']]
```

As you can see, it reads the blank line properly and reads the complete file.  You issue is with how you are attempting to use a blank row as though it is not blank.  You simply need to check the row before you use it:

```
if row:
    #do something
else:
    #blank row
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip empty rows from csv reader by checking the return list

```
for row in csv.reader(file):
    if not row:
       continue
    ...
```